# How can I synchronously load resource with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, typescript, synchronization

I need some files to be loaded synchronously before the main execution of the javascript code.

As an exemple, I have multiple JSON lang file and I want them before generating the HTML. The loaded JSON depends on the browser environment.

Adapting the application to generate the HTML in a callback method is not a good option as the core of our application is already done and multiple programmers works on it.

As synchrone XMLHttpRequest is deprecated, is there another solution?

We are using Typescript.

Comment: I don't understand how this is linked with Typescript. What rendering engine are you using server and client side?

Comment: TypeScript compiles to JavaScript, so anything you do in JavaScript can be done in TypeScript. For this specific question, there are many solutions. Some applications show a "Loading..." screen while the necessary files are loaded, for instance. If you are trying to implement a specific solution, we can probably help.

Comment: So you want a xmlhttprequest that is not synchronous or asynchronous? That can't be done

Answer (score 0):

> I need some files to be loaded synchronously before the main execution of the 
>   javascript code.

## Files up front

If you know the files *beforehand* i.e. they never change based on user input you should probably use a module bundler to bundle them. E.g `webpack` : https://github.com/webpack/raw-loader

## Files on demand

If these files are to be requested on demand, you *should* make the async request and *continue* when you have the result. e.g. instead of

```
   var x = loadFile('somefile');
   // some code
```

You would

```
   loadFile('somefile').then(()=>
     {
       //some code
     }
   );
```

Here the continuation is a `promise`, using something like `fetch` : https://github.com/github/fetch